# Where Federation authentication token is saved [WIF STS]?

Tags: .net, wif, windows-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

While i started to explore WIF, i have a doubt on the following:

In the Windows Identification Foundation[WIF],looking on to Security Token Service[STS], i wish to know where the **federation authentication token** is being saved?

I think its in browser cookie, if so can anyone please give me a insight about it?

Comment: Welcome to the world of Windows Identity Foundation :-)

Answer (score 3):

I used the 'Fiddler' Web debugger to find the answer to this question.  Here's what happens:  Let's suppose that the name of your application is `SecureApp` and the name of your STS is `SecurePortal`.

The first thing that happens when you point your browser at `SecureApp` is that it checks to see if you're authenticated.  If you're not, you are immediately redirected to `SecurePortal` with a query string indicating that you're logging into `SecureApp`.

Once you log in with `SecurePortal`, the WIF framework produces an `HttpResponse` from `SecurePortal` which contains some 'hidden' HTML fields containing values which indicate that you successfully logged in.  These values may be signed and/or encrypted based on the setup of `SecurePortal`.  Along with these values is written some Javascript code to make the browser post the values to `SecureApp`.  Once these values are validated by `SecureApp`, the framework will write an `HttpResponse` with cookie(s) that indicate that you are logged in.  In my experience, the names of the cookies start with "FedAuth".  At this point, you may now access pages within `SecureApp`.

Also, I would like to point out that the framework seems to have some way of preventing the cookies that it sets from being removed manually.

I suggest that you use a web debugger and observe this process happening on your own to understand better.

**The short answer: The token is first given to your browser as an `HttpResponse` in the STS and then given to your browser again as a cookie in the application.**

Answer (score 0):

WIF also supports "Session Mode" for Tokens. In that case, the token is kept in the server and only a (much smaller) handle is passed to the browser. Especially useful if you have bandwidth considerations.

See Vittorio's post on this: [Session mode for WIF](https://web.archive.org/web/20150228183457/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vbertocci/archive/2010/05/26/your-fedauth-cookies-on-a-diet-issessionmode-true.aspx)

**Added more references:**

Hervey's [session at last PDC](https://web.archive.org/web/20100616142443/http://microsoftpdc.com:80/Sessions/SVC17) also covers this.