# Federated Identity- Windows Identity Server - disable cookies in the browser

Tags: .net, wif, federated-identity

I see that Federated Identity stores Security token to a cookie, after its first request to the STS(Secure Token Service). In that case if I disable cookie in my browser, how does it work.

Does the authentication module again connects to the STS to retrieve the user information or 
will it throw any error ?

Is there any way that I can use federated authentication cookieless ?

Answer (score 0):

First, please see this discussion for what happens when you log on.  [Where Federation authentication token is saved [WIF STS]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897422/where-federation-authentication-token-is-saved-wif-sts/2899628#2899628)

I believe that you would need to override a number of classes in the WIF framework to have anything resembling a 'cookieless' Windows Identity Foundation.  I wouldn't recommend it.

I tried disabling cookies in my browser.  The result is that once I log in, I get immediately redirected back to the STS.  I had somewhat expected to see an error message, but there was none.